# Spring - how to bootstrap web app to previously created ApplicationContext

Tags: java, spring, servlets, spring-mvc, jboss

I have an application that heavily uses spring and packaged as **.sar** archive.

Spring context created in managed bean on application deploy:

```
AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext springContext = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext(spring.xml);
```

Now i need to add web functionality to this app, so i repack it as **.ear** and embed **.war** into it.

some servlet registered in `web.xml`:

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>myServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>me.myself.MyServlet</servlet-class>
  </servlet>
```

How do i autowire beans from springContext into `MyServlet`?